# Tensorflow: easy classification does not converge

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to port the "MNIST For ML Beginners" tutorial to an other dataset. As my dataset I chose [wine](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine) which seems to be well used for classification test task.
I read the CSV according to a Programmers Guide article which seems to be not available anymore?

The problem is that my accuracy does not convergate. The values are e.g.

```
0.0
0.0
0.266667
0.6
0.666667
0.666667
0.466667
0.266667
0.0
0.133333
0.0666667
0.0
0.0
0.0666667
0.333333
0.4
0.866667
0.4
0.466667
0.266667
0.133333
0.133333
0.133333
0.0666667
0.0
0.0
0.333333
0.6
0.733333
0.733333
0.333333
0.133333
0.266667
0.0666667
```

I tried printing the my weight matrix to use if it changed after some epochs and it is changed. So why is my net not converging?

I already used the high-level Estimater API which works pretty well for this dataset but I want to learn it also from an low level point.

Maybe the problem is normalization? Is the normalization right to normalize column-wise?

My Code is

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf

### some constants ####
MAX_STEPS = 1000
NUM_ATTRIBUTES = 13
NUM_TYPES = 3


def read_from_cvs(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    _, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    record_defaults = [[] for col in range(
        NUM_ATTRIBUTES + 1)]
    features = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
    examples = tf.stack(features[1:], name="features")
    labels = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(tf.stack(features[0]), tf.int32), NUM_TYPES + 1, name="labels")
    return examples, labels


def input_pipeline(filename='my_dataset.csv', batch_size=15, num_epochs=None):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
    features, labels = read_from_cvs(filename_queue)

    min_after_dequeue = 2 * batch_size
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
    feature_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [features, labels], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    return feature_batch, label_batch

def softmax():
    x, y_ = input_pipeline()

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([NUM_ATTRIBUTES, NUM_TYPES + 1], stddev=0.1), name="weights")
b = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([NUM_TYPES + 1], stddev=0.1), name="bias")    
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()


    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

    x = tf.nn.l2_normalize(x,1) # is my dataset normalized right this way?
    try:
        i = 0
        while not coord.should_stop() and i < MAX_STEPS:
            _, accu = sess.run([train_step, accuracy])
            print(accu)
            i += 1
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        pass

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

    sess.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    softmax()
```

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

The dataset features are highly unormalized. Divide each column of the dataset by its average and divide by the standard deviation in your input pipeline.

Also consider a different optimizer. Gradient descent is conceptually simple but in practice gets blown out of the water by others. My personal favourite is AdamOptimizer, but you can play with others.

Comment: Shouldn't this be done by x = tf.nn.l2_normalize(x,1) in my code?

Comment: That will normalize over the batch, which will do something... but it's (a) inefficient and (b) not as reliable. Also try a different optimizer - answer updated.

Comment: Oh, actually, your normalization isn't doing anything. You're doing it -after- your network. `x = blah(x)` doesn't change the tensor initially referenced by `x` - it just changes what `x` references. This isn't specific to tensorflow. For example, `x = 3; y = x + 2; x = x + 5` will result in `y` being `5`, not `10`. The final statement doesn't effect preceding ones.

Comment: Ok thanks. I wounder if there is a more efficient way to normalize it as you suggested instead of building for-loops on my own and calculate every element on my own.

Comment: Your dataset is small enough you can just load it all into a numpy and use `x -= np.mean(x, axis=0); x /= np.std(x, axis=0);` or if you don't want to change your input pipeline just save the mean and std values and apply them to each bach.

Comment: What would be the way if I have bigger dataset which does not fit into ram at once?

Comment: Loops. Big loops.

Comment: I normalized it this way and replaces Gradient descent with Adam but still run into the same problem. Is your numpy code äquivalent to using tensorflow built-in mean, var = tf.nn.moments(x_old, [1], keep_dims=True); x = tf.div(tf.subtract(x_old, mean), tf.sqrt(var))